# Installing openLDAP

Tags: configuration, installation, openldap

I have followed installing openLDAP from http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html and follow the tasks up to # 9. when I run  [ su root -c /usr/local/libexec/slapd ]
it asks for password and after I type the password no indication of if server has been started or not. When I run [ ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' namingContexts ] I get this error [ ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)  ]  I can't figure it out what is the problem.
Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: did it compile and build correctly? what linux distro/OS are you using?

Comment: That is because you are trying to bind non-anonymously. Try this:
ldapsearch -h ldapserver.example.com -p 389 -LLLx -b 'dc=example,dc=com' -s base

Comment: Instead of using -x use -LLLx

Answer (score 1):

It may be that slapd finds your configuration invalid, and therefore doesn't start.

To test this, run slaptest, with the same options and permissions. This should output error messages if something is wrong with the config. So something like:

```
su root -c /usr/local/libexec/slaptest
```

Answer (score 1):

try following commands to check whether slapd actually started:

```
netstat -ptnl #(provide list of all servers running)
```

something like below will come:

```
Proto Recv-Q    Send-Q   Local Address         Foreign Address  State   PID/Program name
tcp        0        0      0.0.0.0:1394           0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      24000/slapd
tcp        0        0      139.54.136.132:1395     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      23927/slapd
```

OR

```
ps -ef |grep slapd
```

something like below will come:

```
root 9147 1  0 16:13 ?  00:00:00 slapd -h ldap://172.21.140.73:1389 -f /usr/local/etc/openldap2-4-30/slapd.conf
root     29285 11091  0 17:16 pts/6    00:00:00 grep slapd
```

If slpad process is not listed by any of the above commands it means slapd is not started.

In this case you can try to run slpad with debug options:

```
slapd -d -1
```

-1 will enable all debugging. There are various other options you can google for these.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ps` is the slapd process listed?  What is in the logs?